# HTML: Jump to specific part of page on POST

Tags: html, forms, post, razor

As the title says,

I know this can be done with a for example `<a href="#title">`, but can this be achieved on `if (IsPost)` as well? Not when the page loads for the first time, only on `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

After you handle your post request. You redirect your user to a page. There you can put #location

```
Window.location('hello.html#afterPost');
```